# Eagerly loading multiple levels with EF 5, .NET 4.5 and Linq

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework, eager-loading

I have a data structure that contains countries, each country can contain multiple tournaments, each tournament can contain multiple matches, each match has 2 teams (home team and away team).  The data is setup in a normal hierarchy with primary and foreign keys.  I'd like to get a list of countires where all of the child data is eagerly loaded beneath them for all matches played on a specific date.
This was the sort of thing I though I'd need, although the systax is all wrong.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Thank you.

```
            var countries = Context.sbsCountries
            .Include(c => c.Tournaments
               .Select(t => t.Matches)
                   .Select(m => m.TeamHome)
                   .Select(m => m.TeamAway)
                        )
                    )
            .Where(m => m.date == providedDate)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Edited)

A way to do this is load the required matches first with the specified data included and then fetch the countries

```
var matches = from m in context.Matches
                       .Include(m => m.Tournament)
                       .Include(m => m.TeamHome)
                       .Include(m => m.TeamAway)
              where m.Date == providedDate
              select m;
matches.Load();
var countries = context.sbsCountries.ToList();
```

Entity framework will automagically fix up the right associations, so each country has its own `Matches` on the provided date.

To make this work, you should turn off lazy loading, otherwise when you address a county's Matches collection it will be loaded entirely at that moment (if the context is still alive).

Another way could be to start the query on matches (again with lazy loading disabled) and select distinct countries through the `Tournaments`:

```
var matches = (from m in context.Matches
                        .Include(m => m.Tournament)
                        .Include(m => m.TeamHome)
                        .Include(m => m.TeamAway)
               where m.Date == providedDate
               select m.Tournament.Country).Distinct();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, in both of these examples what would happen to tournaments (they sit between countires and matches)?

Comment: I overlooked that, but it is not too hard (fortunately) to insert the Tournament level. See the edited answer.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks, dont think it was helping that I was thinking about the problem from the top down.